# Python sendmail, error

Tags: python, windows, unix, sendmail

I am getting an additional content as given bellow when I am sending mail from unix server using python `sendmail.`This content is displayed in the mail.

```
From nobody Mon Dec 18 09:36:01 2017 Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii" MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

My code is as follows.

```
   #reading data from file
   data = MIMEText(file('%s'%file_name).read())
   #writing the content as html
   content = MIMEText("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title></head><body>"+'%s'%data+"</body></html>", "html")
   msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative")

   msg["From"] = "sender@mail.com"
   msg["To"] = "mymailid@mail.com"
   msg["Subject"] = "python mail"

   msg.attach(content)

   p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t","-oi"], stdin=PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
   p.communicate(msg.as_string())
```

Comment: I just want to avoid that, warning. My file content is an html data, but when I receive mail, I am seeing this warning above my message. I want to disable that.

Comment: I suspect you also need to explicitly identify `data` as being "html". `data = MIMEText(whatever, "html")`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755501/embed-picture-in-email/7755994#7755994

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are constructing the email content in two parts, as `data` and `content`. You need to explicitly confirm that both are HTML. So change

```
data = MIMEText(file('%s'%file_name).read())
```

to

```
data = MIMEText(file('%s'%file_name).read(), "html")
```

Comment: Thanks, Actually my mistake was, I have added to multiple HTML headers to the data, the step:



`content = MIMEText("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title></head><body>"+'%s'%data+"</body></html>", "html")`



was not necessary, just reading the file content as HTML is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the message string. The message you see is not a warning, it is just what **you** have writen into the message with:

```
data = MIMEText(file('%s'%file_name).read())
content = MIMEText("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title></head><body>"
    +'%s'%data+"</body></html>", "html")
```

`data.as_string()` actually contains `Content-Type: text/plain; ...` because it has been added by the first `MIMEText` line, when you want to include it into the body of a HTML page.

What you really want is probably:

```
data = file(file_name).read()
content = MIMEText("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title></head><body>"
    +'%s'%data+"</body></html>", "html")
```

But I also think that you do not need to include it into another level with a `MIMEMultipart("alternative")`: `msg = content` is probably enough.

Finally, I do not think that explicitely starting a new process to execute sendmail is really overkill, when the `smtplib` module from the standard library aloready knows how to send a message:

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP()
server.send_message(msg)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, Actually my mistake was, I have added to multiple HTML headers to the data, the step:



`content = MIMEText("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title></head><body>"+'%s'%data+"</body></html>", "html")`



was not necessary, just reading the file content as HTML is fine.