# How to insert images in body while sending emails with python

Tags: python, image, email, smtp, smtplib

Can I insert an image in the msg area, can do as an attachment or as an html code.
I have tried as html code but it just outputs the html code as a string.

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib

SenderAddress='<xxxx@gmail.com>'

e = pd.read_excel("C:-=-.Email.xls")
emails = e['Emails'].values
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com:587")
server.starttls()
server.login('xxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxx')

msg = 'image here'

subject = "Test"
body = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject,msg.as_string())
for email in emails:
  server.sendmail(SenderAddress, email, body)
server.quit()
```

Comment: [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRCJ6RtE3xU&t=1035) will help you

Comment: this should help, already answered:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755501/embed-picture-in-email

Comment: Thank you, I was able to fix the problem with modifying my code with the code you referenced.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed picture in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755501/embed-picture-in-email)