# Python Emailing Multipart with body content

Tags: python, email, smtp, mime

I can't send an e-mail in python with a body as a multipart email. Everything I've tried has resulted in all of the content as attachments, and I can't get the text or html to show up in the body.

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
if msg_mime_type == 'text' or not msg_mime_type:
    new_body = MIMEText(body, 'text')
elif msg_mime_type == 'image':
    new_body = MIMEImage(body)
elif msg_mime_type == 'html':
    new_body = MIMEText(body, 'html')
new_body.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'inline', filename='body')
msg.set_payload(new_body) #also tried msg.attach(new_body)
```

I need to use a `Multipart` so that i can also add attachments, but I kept that code out for simplicity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify that the parts are alternatives of one another, e.g. the `multipart/alternative` mime type:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
```

The default is `mixed`; see the [email library examples](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html).

Note that to create an email with both attachments and an alternative (HTML / CSS) option you'll need to have a top-level `multipart/related` container that contains the `alternative` parts as the first entry.

Comment: now yahoo registered no body or attachments, gmail registered it as an attachment

Comment: @notbad.jpeg: you'll need to nest mime parts; the main message is multipart/alternative (reader can pick either HTML or Text) but the rest of the messages need to be part of your email but not part of the alternatives.

Comment: yeah this hasn't helped me at all, it actually confused me more, maybe you could post a larger code snippet?

Comment: Example `alternative` multipart message building here on SO: [Python: Sending Multipart html emails which contain embedded images](http://stackoverflow.com/q/920910)

Comment: Example on the Python Recipes site: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576931-send-a-multipart-email/