# Sending HTML emails out from Plone

Tags: html, email, plone

Are there examples of sending simple HTML formatted emails (`<h1>`, `<b>` and such) out from Plone?

Plain text is well-covered, but there are no HTML email out examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adapt any of the many python [`email` module](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html) examples. Because HTML email *usually* means sending multipart/alternative messages, things get a little more complicated.

- The [examples page](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html) of the `email` package.
- [Sending HTML email using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-in-python)
- [Sending Multipart html emails which contain embedded images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920910/python-sending-multipart-html-emails-which-contain-embedded-images)

You basically have to construct an `email.Message` object and pass that to `Mailhost.send`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, you could also use [collective.watcherlist](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.watcherlist).
This was factored out of Products.Poi, which uses it to allow users to subscribe to updates for an issue.  That part may not be interesting for you, but it has code that takes a browserview as basis for sending an email.  Hooking a page template up to that browserview is of course simple.

If you cannot use it directly, it may serve as a code example.