# Send image in Email Body using Java

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have been able to send Image as an Attachment in an Email using Java. I am now trying to send the same image in the Email Body Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchProviderException, MessagingException {
    System.out.println("Sending mail...");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");

props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "mysusername");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.password", "mypassword");

    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    mailSession.setDebug(true);
    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    message.setSubject("HTML  mail with images");
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myaddress@gmail.com"));
    message.setContent
      ("<h1>This is a test</h1>" 
       + "<img src=\"C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Photos/Shammah.PNG\">", 
       "text/html");
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
         new InternetAddress("receiver@simbatech.biz"));

    transport.connect();//This is line 46
    transport.sendMessage(message,
        message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
    transport.close();
}
```

I am getting this output:

```
Sending mail...
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4ea
DEBUG: getProvider() returning        javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:306)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
at image.in.body.ImageInBody.main(ImageInBody.java:46)
Java Result: 1
```

Why is authentication failing while I am using the correct username and Password for My Gmail account?

Comment: The errors concern authentication not your actual body content... something is wrong in your settings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to declare your images like this :

```
<img src="cid:unique-name-or-id" />
```

Load images as MimeBodyPart and match the unique-name-or-id with the FileName of the MimeBodyPart.

Answer (score 12):

see the below code may be use full

```
class SimpleMail2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        System.out.println("Sending mail...");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("sender@gmail.com","password");
            }
        });
        Message message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sender@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("HTML  mail with images");
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("receiver@gmail.com"));
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String htmlText = "<H1>Raghava chary</H1>" + "<img src=\"cid:image\">";
        messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        try {
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            InputStream imageStream = SimpleMail2.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ab/log.gif");
            DataSource fds = new ByteArrayDataSource(IOUtils.toByteArray(imageStream), "image/gif");
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<image>");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            message.setContent(multipart);
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and add org.apache.commons.io.jar.zip and axiom-api-1.2.6.jar and add mail.jar and activation.jar

Answer (score 2):

Create a multipart body with content-disposition inline and encode in base64 your image.

Check this SO for some details (in Python) [Sending Multipart html emails which contain embedded images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920910/python-sending-multipart-html-emails-which-contain-embedded-images)

Answer (score 1):

First, see this JavaMail FAQ entry of [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Then, see this JavaMail FAQ entry with [sample code for connecting to Gmail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).

Note that there is no "mail.smtp.password" property.  Since you're not supplying a password, authentication is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Another common mistake (bit me today):  the Content-ID header for the image must be in <angle brackets>. Failure to do so will break some mail programs (gmail, OS X 10.10) but not others (Outlook, iOS <= 8.1).

Comment: well, this ended a long and confusion mystery. thanks!