# Email Error help me with syntax error

Tags: python, email, smtplib

```
import smtplib  
from email import encoders
from email.message import Message
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg.attach(MIMEText(file("P:/Email/test.txt").read()))



sender = 'sender@email.com'  
reciever  = 'reciever@email.com'  
msg = 'Hello'  


# Credentials (if needed)  
username = 'user'  
password = 'pass'  

# The actual mail send  
server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')  
server.starttls()  
server.login(username,password)  
server.sendmail(sender, reciever, msg)  
server.quit()
```

Traceback (most recent call last): File "attach2.py", line 27, in 
server.sendmail(sender, reciever, msg) File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 775, in 
sendmail (code, resp) = self.data(msg) File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 516, in
data q = _quote_periods(msg) File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 167, in 
quote_periods return re.sub(br'(?m)^.', b'..', bindata) File "C:\Python33\lib\re.py",
line 170, in sub return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count) TypeError: 
expected string or buffer

why am i seeing this error message. is there something wrong with my python library file?

Comment: You should add a tag for which language this is to attract more attention. The email tag alone has very few followers.

Comment: which language this is ?

Comment: You need to add a language tag. With that being said, **actually read the code you posted**. You've declared `msg = MIMEMultipart()`, and used it once already as `msg.attach`, so you clearly can't now refer to it in line 10 with `msg = 'Hello'`. I'm not even sure what language this is, and *I* can see that mistake.

Comment: my code in PYTHON 3.3

Comment: Welcome! I have deleted my answer since you have updated the question and know it has changed completely. You have to understand that this is not a debugging site. In a case like this, I would suggest to open different questions instead of editing the same one. This will confuse people coming to this particular question and having answers that do not match the question anymore.

Answer (score 3):

The previous line is missing a closing parenthesis.

```
...
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg.attach(MIMEText(file("P:/Email/test.txt").read())) # line missing a parenthesis

sender = 'whosends@something.com'
...
```

Comment: i thought i fixed that already. hmmm. let me try msg.attach(MIMEText(file("P:/Email/test.txt").read()))

Comment: still the same error message.     msg.attach(MIMEText(file("P:/Email/test.txt").read()))
NameError: name 'file' is not defined

Comment: that works! but new error. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "attach2.py", line 27, in <module>
    server.sendmail(sender, reciever, msg)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 775, in sendmail
    (code, resp) = self.data(msg)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 516, in data
    q = _quote_periods(msg)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 167, in _quote_periods
    return re.sub(br'(?m)^\.', b'..', bindata)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\re.py", line 170, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Tuan, This is hard so parse. Can you post it in your original question with formatting?

Comment: sorry. this site is so hard to use.

Comment: i am trying to create a python code that can attach an excel sheet to an email. the only example i gathered was the code above. but when running it. i runs into problems. i dont have the know how or enough knowledge to fix the bugs from  the code. this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649130/python3-multipartmime-email-text-email-and-attachment actually provides me with the working code but when running it. i dont see emails being sent out. but a file named msgtest.eml was created and it look like its supposed to be the email sent.

Comment: Tuan, what I meant is the Traceback you posted in another comment should be posted to your original question on the top of the page. Please click the `edit` link and copy/paste the error there (ensuring it is formatted properly).

Comment: its my first day using this site. everyone here are helpful though. thanks!

Comment: Tuan, Can you format the output of the tracebalk? Put 4 spaces before each line (you did this when you posted your code originally).

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 2 errors. Here is my Correcting

```
import smtplib  
from email import encoders
from email.message import Message
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg.attach(MIMEText(file("P:/Email/test.txt").read()))



sender = 'sender@email.com'  
reciever  = 'reciever@email.com'  

# ***here don't overwrite the MIMEMultipart() obj***
# msg = 'Hello'  


# Credentials (if needed)  
username = 'user'  
password = 'pass'  

# The actual mail send  
server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')  
server.starttls()  
server.login(username,password)

# ***here msg.as_string() to convert the MIMEMultipart() obj to a string***
server.sendmail(sender, reciever, msg.as_string())  

server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

this code worked well

```py
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# ...

def send_mail(content):
    message = MIMEText(json.dumps(content))
    message["Subject"] = "Alert!"
    message["From"] = "alert@info.com"
    message["To"] = "abbas.kh@gmail.com"
    try:

        with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mailtrap.io", 2525) as server:
            server.set_debuglevel(1)
            server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
            server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
            server.login("3247bc881dc002", "e6961e84f746ee")
            server.sendmail(message["From"] , message["To"], message.as_string())
        print('Sent')
    except smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected:
        print('Failed to connect to the server. Wrong user/password?')
    except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
        print('SMTP error occurred: ' + str(e))
    except Exception as e:
        print('everything else')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).