# HTML/RICH emails dynamically sent from Python

Tags: html, python-2.7, email, smtplib

I have what I thought was a simple task to do, that has now snow balled into something else. I wrote a simple python script that would generate simple customer notification over email in plain text using smtplib pretty simple.

Now when trying to make a more rich email, like those that Paypal,Amazon etc send, I run into some problems. Having read a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920910/sending-multipart-html-emails-which-contain-embedded-images) and coupled with what I thought was a universal template I got from [here](http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-email-templates) I felt armed to complete my task.

However I keep reading about fragmentation and how various email clients don't support all sorts of tags and when I open it on my Hotmail client on Android it looks perfect but when I open the same email on chrome (WIN) on Hotmail it misses some buttons styling. Let me not even get started how it looks on Yahoo mails Android client (I know you are now wondering who cares who still uses Yahoo or Hotmail but a lot of people still do).

Where as Amazon and Paypal emails look consistent in styling across all platforms,clients and email providers. I can't find a simple resource that clearly describes away to make a truly robust way of serving html content on email.

Can someone share a resource of how to do this with python?

Comment: Did you think of some options like using MailChimp?

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this is helpful to you.

http://mailchimp.com/resources/email-design-guide/