# python smtplib - send mail fails using msgRoot.as_string()

Tags: python, email

im adapating a script as per [Sending Multipart html emails which contain embedded images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920910/sending-multipart-html-emails-which-contain-embedded-images/920928#920928) and when Ive come to sending the mail, it fails but im not getting any return codes as to why it may have failed just a blank code. im using an internal mxrelay setup by our sysadmins.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "infternal.settings")
import django
django.setup()
from django.conf import settings
import dateutil.parser
import re
import requests
import json
from O365 import *
from sites.models import SiteData
from sites.models import Circuits, CircuitMaintenance
from home.models import MailTemplate, MailImages
from jinja2 import Template, Environment
from django.db.models import Q
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.conf import settings
from StringIO import StringIO
import smtplib    
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage

env = Environment(autoescape=False, optimized=False)       
template_data = MailTemplate.objects.get(pk=1)
mail_template = env.from_string(template_data.template)

template_file = StringIO()
mail_template.stream(
    StartDate   = '17/02/17 Midnight',
    EndDate     = '17/02/17 6 AM',
    Details     = 'Circuit maintenace on the cirasodasd asdas da a dskdka aks ada',   
).dump(template_file)

content = template_file.getvalue()

# Define these once; use them twice!
strFrom = 'helpdesk@xxxxx.com'
strTo = 'alex@xxxx.com'

# Create the root message and fill in the from, to, and subject headers
msgRoot = MIMEMultipart('related')
msgRoot['Subject'] = 'test message'
msgRoot['From'] = strFrom
msgRoot['To'] = strTo
msgRoot.preamble = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.'

# Encapsulate the plain and HTML versions of the message body in an
# 'alternative' part, so message agents can decide which they want to display.
msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msgRoot.attach(msgAlternative)

msgText = MIMEText('This is the alternative plain text message.')
msgAlternative.attach(msgText)

# We reference the image in the IMG SRC attribute by the ID we give it below
msgText = MIMEText(content, 'html')
msgAlternative.attach(msgText)

mail_images = MailImages.objects.filter(mail_template=template_data)

count = 1
for i in mail_images:
    fp = open('{0}{1}'.format(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,i.image), 'rb')
    msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', 'image_{0}'.format(count))
    msgRoot.attach(msgImage)
    count += 1

# Send the email (this example assumes SMTP authentication is required)
smtp = smtplib.SMTP()
smtp.connect('mxrelay.xxxx.com')
smtp.sendmail(strFrom, strTo, msgRoot.as_string())
smtp.quit()
```

output of sending below:

```
>>> smtp.connect('mxrelay.xxxxx.com')
(220, 'mxrelay-02.xxxxx.com ESMTP Postfix')
>>> smtp.sendmail(strFrom, strTo, msgRoot.as_string())
{}
>>>
```

I thought it might be the embedded images failing so i took that bit out and still got nothing back.
does anyone know why i would not be returned a response code?

Thanks

*EDIT:

if i send smtp.sendmail(strFrom, strTo, 'TEST') i get the email, but sending msgRoot.as_string() fails, in either response though the code is {} but it works so it must be something to do with the msg, and comparing the code posted by Aidan i cant see any differences that would cause it to fail

Comment: You have posted two sets of code here. Which one is it that you want help with?

Comment: i dont think i have, this is one piece of code for sending email, perhaps the second import threw you? ive moved it to the top. Thanks

Comment: What gives `print(msgRoot.as_string())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. pretty much taken straight from python 2.7 documentation.

```
        """
https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/email-examples.html
"""
from __future__ import print_function
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from smtplib import SMTPException

import smtplib
import datetime


COMMASPACE = ', '


def send_email(username, password, host, port, frmaddr, toaddrs, subj, 
               img_file, html):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = subj
    msg['From'] = frmaddr
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(toaddrs)



    # Open the files in binary mode.  Let the MIMEImage class automatically
    # guess the specific image type.
    with open(img_file, 'rb') as fb:
        img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
        msg.attach(img)

    # attach some html alongside your image.
    msg.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html'))

    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(host, port)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(username, password)
        server.sendmail(frmaddr, toaddrs, msg.as_string())
        server.close()

        log_msg = "email sent from {} to {} at {}" \
                  "".format(frmaddr, ", ".join(toaddrs),
                            datetime.datetime.utcnow())
        print(log_msg)
    except SMTPException as e:
        print(e)

"""
main function
"""
if __name__ == '__main__':
    username = input('Enter your email address: ')      # my_email@gmail.com
    password = input('Enter your password: ')
    host = input('Enter your host: ')   # smtp.gmail.com
    port = input('Enter your port: ')   # 587
    frmaddr = input('Enter the 'from' address: ')
    toaddrs = input('Enter the 'to' addresses (comma delimiter strings): ')
    subj = input('Enter your email subject: ')
    img_file = input('Enter your image file: ')


    send_email(username, password, host, port, frmaddr, toaddrs, subj=subj,
               img_file, html)
```